# Windows service connecting to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

We are running a windows service and the service runs fine during the day but during night we are getting error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server is not responding in the event logs

This service connect to the SQL database. During night there is not much load on the server but still we can see the error. Can you please help?

We  tried increasing the connection time out in web.config but did not help.

Comment: if i were you i would try to connect to db at night times. So lets see if the problem on the client side(on your application) or the server side(sql server). Maybe during the night there is an access restriction on server side.

Comment: @ArgeKumandan is correct. You're not giving us enough information to exclude things like database locks, users online, backup times, or simply the DBA has decided the server should go to sleep at night to save electricity! LOL.. sorry but anything outside your service could be denying you access. Eliminate all or any bottlenecks first

Comment: @ArgeKumandan We tried connecting to the database and able to connect.We have checked with DBA's about the deadlocks,backups etc and they dont find any issues with SQL server.

Comment: @akhilPatel the only thing comes my mind is a firewall that get activates at nigh time and denying your requests. i mean there is no other possibility. there is something denying your reqest physically